# Unable to mark an answer duplicate(as there is no marked answer) and dupilicate answers deleted by a moderator

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, duplicate-answers

I had posted an answer to [Animate counter when in viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946023/2142994)

The same answer was posted by me to an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276583/jquery-make-number-count-up-when-in-viewport/36946000#36946000) I found without any Ticked answers.

I had to post an answer to the new post since the older one had no answers and hence I was unable to tag it a duplicate.
[image]

Now the moderator has deleted it stating :

[image]

I had to post an answer since the other post had no ticked answer and I was unable to mark duplicate. Kindly undelete the answer or mark the question as a duplicate to [point to my answer on the older post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946000/2142994).

Edit : 
***There is no use commenting on the duplicate question because even after commenting, the question will remain open. And also the other question has no marked answers to refer to.***

Comment: You should have left a comment. You have the reputation to do that. DO NOT copy-paste your answers around.

Comment: The new question also can't be closed because there is an open bounty on it.

Comment: @Tunaki I do but the post will neither be marked duplicate nor be tagged with an answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes that too. Was it wrong to answer it with the same answer? The question is the same!

Comment: You are treating SO like it is a forum.  It is not, duplicate Q+A is not okay.  Just like, say, Wikipedia doesn't accept articles about the exact same subject.  Obviously that would be horrible, same applies to SO.  Questioners commonly treat SO like a forum but we don't hold them responsible for anything, answerers are supposed to know better.

Comment: @HansPassant please read the question again. The duplicate had to be posted as both the questions don't have accepted answers & can't be closed as duplicates. So unless one of the answers get more than two votes there is no point commenting or deleting right answers!

Comment: I ignored that of course.  It is not a good enough reason, should be obvious why.  Pick *one*.

Comment: @HansPassant Pick which one? Unless you close a question which is a duplicate, there will always be two questions and it will very well be like wiki with two articles on the same thing with no accepted answer. I posted it to both expecting at least one of them to accept it so that the other could be tagged duplicate.

Comment: The one that's most suitable to act as the canonical question of course.  That is blindingly obvious, sounds to me that no kind of advice is going to get you to agree.  Bye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use the meta effect or one of the chat rooms. Post details of the two questions and request others to help with closing the new question as a duplicate.

I had the very same issue some time ago. My unvoted and unaccepted answer to an old question was a good match to a new question. I asked for advice in a chat room and a kind person gave my original answer an upvote and that allowed me to flag the new question as a duplicate of the old. (Cannot remember the question nor can I find the relevant chat to give a link here.)

Comment: Yes if there is a way to do that. I would like to do that for these questions. : [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455490/animate-counter-when-in-viewport/36946023#36946023) & [old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276583/jquery-make-number-count-up-when-in-viewport/36946000#36946000). I have one up-vote on the old question.

Comment: @AniMenon You can try http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta

Comment: thanx. I have put it up. Just waiting for the bounty to close.

Answer (score 12):

Posting duplicate answers wastes everybody's time. They waste your time, they waste moderators time (they get automatically flagged), they waste the time of these looking for answers (how annoying is it going to be to find question A with your answer and *then* question B, C or even D with *exactly the same answer*?).

You should be flagging or voting to close as a duplicate.

If the target already has a **decent** but zero scoring answer then you can up-vote it to be able to use it as a duplicate target, (Note: I'm not saying that you should up-vote any old rubbish).

The target won't not have an answer - you've just posted one, though you might have to wait for it to get the upvote you need to be able to use the question as a duplicate target. In the meantime post a comment on the other question linking it to the target.

In the case of a question with an open bounty, either leave a comment or flag the post with the "other" option explaining that the question is a duplicate of *target* explaining why you can't close.

However, you don't always have to close the newer question. If the older question doesn't have any answers, but the newer one does or the newer one is a better description of the problem vote/flag to close the older one.

Comment: ChrisF neither the newer nor the older one has an answer ticked. I have already tagged the answer and explained that its a duplicate for this reason.

Comment: Also there is no use commenting the duplicate answer there as the question will still remain open & the other question has no marked answers to refer to.

Comment: @AniMenon - there needs to be at least one **upvoted** answer not an accepted answer before you can flag/vote to close. So provide your answer to the clearer question and leave a comment on the other one. Then when your answer has been upvoted go back and flag/vote to close.

Comment: Both the questions are fairly clear. The newer one needs an answer immediately(its on bounty) & the older question is not active(its 2 years old).

Comment: @AniMenon because something has a bounty doesn't warrant it any immediacy in getting an answer - just a bit of added attention/exposure to hopefully get it an answer...

Comment: @JonClements I would post a question with a bounty only if I wanted an answer soon. And all that I did is answer it. Its just that I saw a similar post and thought I shall answer that too.

Comment: @AniMenon so if you didn't post a bounty on a question you wouldn't be expecting an answer? :p Anyway - I think from the comments and the answer here you understand why duplicating answers across questions (even with good intentions) is not needed.

Comment: @JonClements I have never posted a duplicate answer and don't intend to do it further. This was a special case where I wanted atleast one of the OPs to accept it so that I could flag the other one to be a duplicate.